# How Ignite cluster works

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, ignite

I m novice to apache ignite.
My requirement is to replace the coherence cache with the ignite cache.

As per my understanding to make the cache distributed used the below cache configuration.

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
  <property name="addresses">
    <list>
          <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
          <value>1xx.xxx.xx.xxx</value>
          <value>1xx.xxx.xx.xxx</value>
          <value>1xx.xxx.xx.xxx</value>
          <value>1xx.xxx.xx.xxx</value>
          <value>myapplicationport</value>
    </list>
 </property>
</bean>
```

with same configuration Integrating spring boot with ignite developed a microservice and deployed in all the 4 servers.
Could see only in one server my microservice is up and running while in the other servers ignite got stopped.

Even i tried without providing the port only the ip address.

case2:
Deployed only in one server with one ip in cache configuration the cache stopped with 2 days of deployment.
What should be done to make the cache to be up always.
Because we are also planning to migrate a schema of DB into cache.
Please help on this

Comment: Did your nodes form a cluster? Did you see a topology snapshot message with 4 server nodes? Please provide logs, or a least error messages from failed nodes.

Comment: @Denis
Here you are meaning node a server/IP
only if i mention all my servers name and my application port cache configuration file it will discover all the servers and form cluster?

Comment: It was actually a question :) Look at your "Topology snapshot" messages. How many server nodes do you see in them? And why do the nodes fail? And yes, every node should have addresses and ports of every other node including itself in configuration of its IP finder.

Comment: I m not getting any error reponse but getting a loop of same message in logs
2018-05-08 10:46:45.130  WARN 7441 --- [           main] o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi  : Node has not been connected to topology and will repeat join process. Check remote nodes logs for possible error messages. Note that large topology may require significant time to start. Increase 'TcpDiscoverySpi.networkTimeout' configuration property if getting this message on the starting nodes [networkTimeout=5000]

Comment: Make sure, that the node has its own IP and port in its IP finder configuration

Comment: 2018-05-08 10:50:43.903  INFO 28237 --- [p-disco-srvr-#2] o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi  : TCP discovery spawning a new thread for connection [rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1, rmtPort=33839]
2018-05-08 10:50:43.903  INFO 4298 --- [ock-reader-#517] o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi  : Finished serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/185.151.88.177:52812, rmtPort=52812

Comment: 2018-05-08 10:50:43.903  INFO 28237 --- [ock-reader-#913] o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi  : Started serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:33839, rmtPort=33839]
2018-05-08 10:50:43.906  INFO 28237 --- [ock-reader-#913] o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi  : Finished serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:33839, rmtPort=33839

Comment: yeah @Denis using the same ip(server deployed)and ports in the configuration

Comment: Can you upload your full logs and XML configuration from all your nodes somewhere, so I could take a look?